# Design android screen mixing text and graphics, better approach?

Tags: android, ioio

I will like to develop an application in Android 4 that shows some gauges, text, images, etc.
It will display information read from sensors connected to IOIO board (hardware):
- temperature gauges (linear and angular)
- horizontal horizon (10Dof IMu)
- speed (vertical gauge)
- altitud (vertical gauge)
- etc...

Basically like a Garmin G1000 but the horizontal horizon will be displayed in a square (not all the screen). For example this image: [Garmin G1000 image](http://sitelife.aviationweek.com/ver1.0/Content/images/store/5/8/25ca51f4-4712-4370-98a0-d172803ea4df.Large.jpg)

The screen will contain text and graphics. Some graphic may change high frequently (horizontal horizon, speed, etc), but other no (temperatures, fuel qty, etc).
I was wondering what is the best approach to do it: draw all the screen with canvas, or put text with Textview and graphics with transparent bitmaps, or other options.
I will like if someone could say me what he think about the best approach to design it and to organize the visual components.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With android, your design space is quit limited. So for something like that i would suggest nesting some layouts. You'd set one for the background and others for what ever function you wanna do. I also suggest planning what you wanna display and what layout is best optimized for the function.Eg:

- Use a relative layout to set the landscape background
- Use the Liner layout for the ruler functions on the sides
- Use grid layouts for maps maybe
- Use Split action tabs for the options at the bottom
- Use menus for calibration settings
- Use Relative layouts for all the funny gauges moving about and textboxes and stuff.

Then from there it's a matter of making everything work.
Here are some links on layouts: 
[Link 1](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) [Link 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: Awesome...best of luck with your system